# how to convert ngx-file-drop UploadFile to File object in angular?

Tags: angular

I drag a PDF file from my computer using `ngx-file-drop`.

The object I get is UploadEvent, does anyone know how I can convert it to an File object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs. There is a plain and simple example. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop

```
public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
    this.files = event.files;
    for (const droppedFile of event.files) {
...
    }
}
```

Comment: the API seems to have changed now